# Dart - allow setting class property only once

Tags: class, dart, properties, final

I'd like to have a property which is settable only once and then ignores further attempts to set it, so noone can accidentally set or reset the value.

I know that `late` can "kinda" do this, but when using `late`, neither the compiler, nor the IDE tell me that calling `doOther()` after calling `doOnce()` will cause an exception.

```
class Foo {
  bool? _bar;
  
  void doOnce() {
    if (_bar == null) {
      _bar = true;
      print('done this once');
    }
  }
  
  void doOther() {
    _bar = false; // this should not be possible when doOnce() is done
    print('done other');
  }
}

void main() {
  Foo foo = Foo();
  foo.doOnce();
}
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-final-variables Is this not desirable?

Comment: You alternatively could replace `_bar` with a setter that does nothing (or that throws an error) if the underlying variable has already been set.  You could give the underlying variable some obnoxious name (e.g. `_barInternalUseOnly_298371`) to prevent accidentally using it without going through the gettter/setter.

Comment: Using `late` could solve the issue, but it would introduce another issue, because neither the compiler, nor the IDE know that calling `doOther()` after `doOnce()` would result in an exception. Maybe I should clearify that I want to ignore further attempts to set `_bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `late final` is as close as it gets:

```dart
class Foo {
  late final int a;
  
  Foo();
  
  void doThing() {
    a = 5;
  }
  
  void doAnotherThing() {
    a = 3;
  }
}

...

void main() {
  final foo = Foo();

  // Uncaught Error: LateInitializationError: Field 'a' has not been initialized.
  // print(foo.a);

  foo.doThing();

  // Prints: 5
  print(foo.a);

  // Uncaught Error: LateInitializationError: Field 'a' has already been initialized.
  // foo.doAnotherThing();
}
```

This gives you the runtime behavior you are looking for, but there is no solution that gives you static compile-time checking for assigning to a `late` (or `late`-ish) variable twice. That's because in order to know that your program is attempting to do so, the compiler would have to inspect every path of your program that could possibly assign to the `late` variable which could take a really long time.

In short, you are going to have to practice your own due diligence instead on relying on the compiler or static analyzer to inform you of your mistakes.